# How do I use chrome.extension.getViews() to send activate a function on the front page of my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How do I use chrome.extension.getViews() to take a variable or activate a function on the front page of my chrome extension?

I have read this documentation http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews but don't feel enlightened from it. I have no problem passing the information the other way with .getBackground but have not yet figured out how to pass in the other direction.

Comment: It returns a list of `window` objects. Example to get a `window` reference for all of your extension pages in a tab, and call a global function of the first result: `var views = chrome.extension.getViews({type:'tab'});views[0].callMethod();`. If you expect more tabs, just loop through the results.

Comment: @RobW Cheers, I just ran it through and have it working with a variation, but it only works when the main page is open. Is it possible to communicate with the front page even when it is closed?

Comment: How do you want to talk with a page that doesn't exist?